# Loading JSON Feeds in Jquery Mobile and Phonegap app

Tags: json, jquery-mobile, cordova, rss

I am new to jquery mobile and dont know much about working with its events and functions.
I am currently developing a phonegap app using jquery mobile.I went through many online tutorials to get started.In my jquery mobile app I have a RSS feed reader that loads my blog posts into the div showing a preloader first.

Now, I somewhere found a tutorial of loading JSON feeds instead of RSS.
But the problem with it is that it loads the posts without showing a mobile loader.I mean if i compile that app for android the user has to wait for a long without knowing whats going on.
I tried the Jquery mobile preloader like in my RSS app.But it still first calls the JSON script and then shows the preloader.

I want to make the JSON one work like the RSS reader which shows a script loader till the posts load.But when i try to do so the JSON feeds do not load. :(

Here is the demo of both the apps.

RSS:
http://silverjewelbox.in/rss

JSON:
http://silverjewelbox.in/mobile

If any one knows actually how to figure that out.I can also provide the code for the needed modifications.
Thank you,

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use Google for a JSONP server because Google caches the searches. Create your own JSONP RSS Feeds Server. See this article on CodeProject with full source code for creating RSS JSONP Feeds for PhoneGap Cordova Mobile Apps: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/788762/PhoneGap-Cordova-JSONP-RSS-Feeds